# Proof of $0! = 1$

Tags: factorial

I have been recently studying binomial theorem and in that we very frequently encounter factorials. But one queer thing which I found is $0!$. Even more queer is its value which is

> $0! = 1$.

I was told this fact and I accepted it(without any proof). But I am still confused about it.

How can we prove that $0!= 1 $?

Comment: It's the definition of the factorial at $n=0$, so there's nothing to prove.

Comment: Basically, this is just a convention. But notice how nicely this agrees with general formula $n!=n\cdot(n-1)!$ (take $n=1$).

Comment: @ireallydonknow So is it really by definition? Is there no proof to it?

Comment: Yes. It's by definition.

Comment: It's a special case of the [empty product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product)

Comment: @user2369284 There isn't a proof as this is the definition. It's a definition we make so that we can make formulas a lot simpler for ourselves. Think about this: why do we say that $1$ is not prime? On the surface, it doesn't seem like we _need_ to, but we say that $1$ isn't prime because it makes theorem statements simpler. Similar reasoning applies here: we don't _need_ to but it makes statements simpler.

Comment: For any cardinal $c$ the notation $c!$ designates the order of the group of permutations of a set of cardinal $c$.

Comment: What is your definition of $n!$? Without a definition you cannot prove anything.

Comment: As the local worshipper of simplicity, I hope my answer wins the "Keep It Simple" award.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can order $n$ elements in $n!$ ways. $0$ elements can be ordered in just one way.
One can choose $k$ of $n$ elements in ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ ways. Obviously,
$$1 = {n\choose n} = \frac{n!}{n!\cdot 0!}\text{.}$$
Also, $0! = 1$ agrees with [Euler's function $\Gamma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), for which $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ holds.

These are not proves, but only good reasons why should $0!$ equal $1$.

Comment: You can also include the point(as others have posted) that $0! = 1$ by definition as $n! = \frac{(n+1)!}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers pointed out, $0! = 1$ is rather a definition than a thing we could prove, but there is some motivation behind it:

1. First of all, it is a common convention, that the empty sum $\sum_\emptyset=0$ has value $0$. It seems to be a natural definition, because if we add something to the sum, we want to be able to sum by forming the disjoint union of the two sets: $$\sum_{x\in A} x + \sum_{x \in \emptyset} x = \sum_{x \in A \cup \emptyset} x = \sum_{x \in A}.$$
   In the same way, we often define $\bigcup_\emptyset =\emptyset$ and $\prod_\emptyset = 1$. The latter gives us: $$n!:=\prod_{k=1}^nk \Rightarrow 0! = \prod_{k=1}^0 = \prod_\emptyset k = 1.$$ Thus, setting $0!$ is consistent to other conventions.
2. Another answer comes from real analysis. By the [Bohr-Mollerup Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem), there is only one function $f:\Bbb R^+ \rightarrow \Bbb R$ that satisfies:

   - $f(x+1)=xf(x) \forall x \in \Bbb R$
   - $f$ is logarithmic convex
   - $f$ interpolates the factorial in a sense that for $n \in \Bbb N$: $f(n+1) = n!$

   This function is the Gamma-function and it has value $\Gamma(1) = 1$ corresponding to  $0! = 1$. Thus setting $0! = 1$ can also be considered to be a natural choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it from the definition of the factorial operation, which defines $0!=1$.  The question you should be asking is *why* we define it this way.

One argument in favor of this definition is that it preserves the important property that $$(n+1)! = (n+1)\cdot n!$$ even when $n=0$.  If we want to use this property to reason about factorials, we either need to accept that $0!=1$ or else be prepared to fill our arguments with special exceptions for $n=0$.

A different kind of argument proceeds from the objects that the factorial function is intended to model.  $n!$ is intended to be the number of ways of making an ordered list of $n$ distinct objects.  So for example $3!=6$ because there are six ways to order a list of three items:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
(123) & (132) & (312) \\
(213) & (231) & (321) \end{array}$$

And $2! = 2$ because there are two ways to order a list of two items:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
(12) & (21)\end{array}$$

And $1!=1$ because there is one way to order a list of one item:

$$\begin{array}{c}
(1)\end{array}$$

And $0!=1$ because there is one way to order a list of zero items:

$$\begin{array}{c}
()\end{array}$$

$()$ is unquestionably a list of zero items, so why wouldn't you count it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$$n! = \frac{(n+1)!}{n+1}$$

So you can apply this for $0$. Actually it's quite nicely explained [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mfk_L4Nx2ZI)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
4! & = 24. \quad \text{Divide by 4 and get:} \\
3! & = 6. \quad \text{Divide by 3 and get:} \\
2! & = 2. \quad \text{Divide by 2 and get:} \\
1! & = 1. \quad \text{Divide by 1 and get:} \\
0! & = 
\end{align}

Fill in the blank.

Not a proof, but this may shed some light.

Also, notice that when you multiply no numbers at all, you get $1$.  That's also been asked about here.  That's why $x^0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proof for this statement, since $0! = 1$ is just a convenient and nice definition in many applications.

For instance, if you would like to think of $n!$ as the number of bijective maps from an $n$ element set to itself, then there is only one bijective map from an empty set to itself.

The other to interpret factorial is through the $\Gamma$ function defined as $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$. If $z \in \mathbb{Z}^+ - \{1\}$, then $\Gamma(z) = (z-1)!$. Hence, if we would like to extend the notion of factorial beyond positive integers using the $\Gamma$ function, setting $z=1$, we get that $1! = 1 \cdot 0!$, which forces $0! = 1$.